# python2.7 in Raspbian Lite

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have installed Raspbian Lite OS in Raspberry Pi zero.

I found that Raspbian Lite comes with Python3 as default.
But I am gonna run some scripts that uses libraries that are Python2 Compatible.

So I tried to change the default Python version from Python3 to Python2 (Specifically Python2.7.18)

After so much searching and trying, instructions from [this page][1] made my job

Now if I try to check in command writing

```
python --version
```

It shows me that it is Python2.7.18

But the problem is I am not being able to install any packages using

```
sudo apt-get install <python-packagename>
```

It shows me Errors like

```
1.Package "python-pip" has no installation candidate (When I tried to install pip)
2. Package python-numpy has no installation candidate (when I tried to install numpy)
3. unable to locate package python-pyaudio (when I tried to install pyaudio)
```

I am searching but no solution.

Can anyone please help? I am frozen in a critical stage of my project .

Comment: As your issue seems to be more related to Debian package management and Raspbian in particular, not Python and software developoment in general, you may find more help at [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) or [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, for new raspbian/raspios os with python 3 by default, it is not suggested to replace the system python interpreter to python 2, it may break some system component's dependency.

Instead, you can create a python 2 virtual env, if you need to run python2 scripts.

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

You can test the python version as following,

```sh
(venv) $ python --version
```